# I found a bug on this website that allowed me to log in on my account without a password

Tags: discussion, bug, security

I think the title says it all. I am kind of worried about this and where can I contact someone so they can fix this problem?

Comment: Questions about the site itself should be posted on [meta]

Comment: Heh, this made the HNQ

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you contacted SE about it and did they react already?

Comment: Yes I contacted them but I do not remember if they contacted me back.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

https://stackexchange.com/about/security

Describe to them in detail what you did, and where the security problem is.

(My guess is that you used external authentication like google or openid)...

Comment: I am using a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and have barely got started with this. Everything was nice and clear and then I got logged in by doing some thing that I am not going to tell how public

Comment: Yes, I was not asking you to disclose anything :) I was merely suggesting that there might be mechanisms that work the way they are intended to, and yet let you in without a password.

Comment: Given the litigious climate that we live nowadays I would use a throwaway account to gauge their reaction

Comment: Was it an accident, or were you actively trying to do it?  (Not looking for details, just wondering.)